# Strategies to verifying physical presence for web checkins

Tags: geolocation, pyramid, mobile-website

My context here is a check-in system for use in classes I conduct, but this applies similarly for any sort of web-based checkin where the device used is not under your physical control (i.e. not those airline or cinema touchscreens). I include the geolocation tag as it may (or may not) be relevant.

## Problem Definition

How can a website verify that the user checking in is physically present in a particular venue, given that no control is assumed over both the user's device (laptop/smartphone/tablet) and internet connection (users will be using their own 3G/4G connections)?

Foolproof security isn't possible here (I believe) due to the restrictions above, so the aim is to maximise security by increasing the complexity of fooling the system (by checking in without being physically present), while minimising process complexity for those who are physically present.

What strategies are possible here, given that I have control of the venue itself and the web service.

## Possible strategies

1. A password which is only provided in the venue without which sign in cannot occur.
2. A QR code displayed on a screen in the venue which must be scanned.
3. Either of the above, but the authorisation element refreshes every N seconds to prevent relaying of the element to external parties.

## Analysis of current strategies

1. This is very simple to use. However passwords are easily obtained by external parties assuming they have contact with at least one internal party (being just text).
2. This is actually not too different from number 1, as a QR code, once scanned, is just text. Complexity is increased as each user needs some form of QR code scanning on their phone, and external parties can still easily obtain the QR code content as it can be forwarded as text.
3. This seems to increase security by preventing the utility of forwarding  passwords as passwords will expire after N seconds. As long as N is short enough, the inherent lag of scanning a QR code and/or the lag associated with message delivery and receipt means it would be fairly difficult for external parties to reliably obtain a current password from an internal user. This can be circumvented using a live video stream of the venue though.

## Additional ideas

1. Some sort of client geolocation (HTML5 supports it, but may not be trivial to add to my web service).
2. Require that a certain wifi ESSID or bluetooth device be present (must be a client-level check, may not be possible depending on device).

Comment: Make your students take and upload a selfie with the password displayed on the screen in the background...

Comment: @Sergey and then I'd have to perform facial recognition?

Comment: No, then you'd have an evidence that the actual person was present at the actual location. You'd then need someone to review the data to confirm that the photos match - I suppose you can only do that if you have some reasons to suspect cheating. In general I suspect having to take a photo would dissuade most "inside helpers".

Comment: Any technical solution based on geolocation or ESSID can be easily fooled - I can give my phone to a friend and ask them to check in for me.

Comment: Ah so your suggestion is to dis-incentivise fooling the system by asking for evidence. Would certainly work for smaller class sizes, but as I expect 200 per class this would likely take up too much time. Thanks though, this is an angle I did not consider.